# Pass parameter from route to controller in laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I want to pass current agency id from route to controller in laravel 5.2.

ex:- I have one resource controller is AgencyController.

```
Route::resource('agencies', 'Admin\AgencyController');
```

I want to add one more route, such as,

```
Route::get('agencies/me', 'Admin\AgencyController@show', ['middleware' => ['web', 'agency']]);
```

Here I want to pass agency id from session as default parameter to `agencyController@show` function.

```
ex:- Auth::guard('agency')->user()->agencies_id
```

Is it possible in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel routes function that if you configure your route like:

`Route::get('user/{user}', 'UserController@someMethod');`

you can pick up whatever you send after the slash in the controller. So if you call:

`www.example.com/user/3`

and your controller is like `public function someMethod($id)` the 3 will be forwarded to `$id` variable